# React hooks being called out of order

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

For some reason, it seems that the useMemo hook is executing before the useEffect hook, directly above it.
I believe this is so because I am receiving an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'timestamp' of undefined

this error points to the `datum.timestamp` in the dependency array for the last useEffect hook and occurs whenever `is_paused` changes from `false => true`.

The problem as I see it, is that the useMemo hook is trying to get an item from an empty array, an array which should have been set by the useEffect before it.

I did some logging, and indeed, I see the log in the useMemo, but not the useEffect.

```js
const [position, setPosition] = useState(MAX_HISTORY - 1);
const [data, setData] = useState<ExData[]>(new Array(MAX_HISTORY).fill({ content: {} }));
const paused_data_ref = useRef<ExData[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const listener = (d: ExData) => {
    const new_data = data.slice(1);
    new_data.push(d);
    setData(new_data);
  };
  addListener(props.event_key, listener);
  return () => {
    removeListener(props.event_key);
  };
});

useEffect(() => {
  paused_data_ref.current = is_paused ? [...data] : [];
  if (is_paused) {
    console.log('copy data array');
  }
}, [is_paused, data]);

const datum = useMemo(() => {
  if (is_paused)
    console.log({
      position,
      data: paused_data_ref.current[position],
      arr: paused_data_ref.current
    });
  return is_paused ? paused_data_ref.current[position] : data[MAX_HISTORY - 1];
}, [is_paused, position, data]);

useEffect(() => {...}, [datum.timestamp])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, the function passed to `useEffect` is called after the function passed to `useMemo`.

According to the React docs:

> The function passed to useEffect will run after the render is committed to the screen.

This means that all `useEffect` calls will happen after the other functions in your component (including a function passed to `useMemo`), even if the `useEffect` is placed earlier in the component.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Comment: Thank you. I was able to refactor my code to get it working. I didn't realize useEffect behaved differently from other hooks.